# Default value of TextBox is "null" in jsp ,when migrate project from java1.4 to java1.8

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jsp-tags, weblogic12c

Recently I have migrated my java project from jdk1.4 to jdk1.8 ,most of the textbox in JSP page ,by default containing "null" inside them , Other field have values coming dynamically from database so how to remove this null, My project consist of near about 300 jsp pages. I am new in java technology.
**I am using weblogic12c as an application server.**
This is working fine in old project

```
<td class="gray" nowrap bgcolor="#dedfde">RMA No.</td>
                        <td nowrap bgcolor="#dedfde"> <span class="gray"> 
                          <input name=tbxRMANo value="<%=strRMANO%>" >
                          </span> </td>
```

This is change in code that i have done to remove "null" and working in new project

```
<td class="gray" nowrap bgcolor="#dedfde">RMA No.</td>
                        <td nowrap bgcolor="#dedfde"> <span class="gray"> 
                          <input name=tbxRMANo value="<%=strRMANO!=null)?strRMANO:""%>" >
                          </span> </td>
```

Comment: can you post your code ?I don't think its because of jdk

Comment: ok i will post my jsp file,but here everything is ok ,but when it will be in running state ,then mostly textbox will be having null as their default value.

Comment: Though you already have `300` jsps using scriplets, you can use an IDE to `find/replace` throughout the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can control it via a setting in the weblogic.xml configuration file:

add **`<wls:print-nulls>false</wls:print-nulls>`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root></wls:context-root>
     <wls:jsp-descriptor>
        <wls:print-nulls>false</wls:print-nulls>
    </wls:jsp-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

you can find the weblogic.xml file in WebContent/WEB-INF directory

the default value for this is true, that is the reason you are seeing nulls.

Comment: Edited my question with Application Server

Answer (score 0):

Though you already have `300` jsps using scriplets, you can use an IDE to `find/replace` throughout the project.

Using EL instead of scriplets, assuming that `strRMANO` is available in any one of the scopes(`page / request / session / application`).

```
<input name=tbxRMANo value="${strRMANO}"/>
```